# deformed object when importing obj file to openGL code

Tags: c, opengl, blender

I am relatively new to openGL and 3D drawing.
I drew a little person in Blender and exported its verteces in a .objfile so I can render that person using my C-code.

this is the person I drew:
[image]

**The problem**

When I import it in my code I don't see a person any more but a horrible ugly mess:

[image]

**What I think**

In the beginning when I tested my software I drew a cube and imported those vertices in my code. I saw that I only had 6 v-vertices. this gave me a partial cube ( hence one side is not closed).

[image]

So maybe it has something to do with that.

What can I do to solve this issue? Where did I make a mistake? Has it something to do with the projection or the export from blender?

**This is my C code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include "myVertices.h"



float xCamera = 3.0;
float yCamera = 3.0;
float zCamera = 0.0;

float barelRollCamera = 0.0;

void init(void)
{
    glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);  
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
}

void drawVertex(GLfloat vertex[][3], int numberVertex, int shape)
{
    int i;

    glPushMatrix();
    switch(shape)
    {
        case 0: glBegin(GL_LINES); break;
        case 1: glBegin(GL_POLYGON); break;
        default: break;
    }

    for(i=0;i<numberVertex;i++)
    {
        glVertex3fv(vertex[i]);
    }

    glEnd();
    glPopMatrix();

}


void drawScene(void)
{

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt(xCamera,yCamera,3.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,1.0,barelRollCamera);
    glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);

    //draws axis
    drawVertex(assen,6,0);

     //draws person I drew in blender using the vertices in my header file
    drawVertex(person,1038,1);

    glFlush();
}

void herschaal(){

    glViewport(0,0,500,500);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glOrtho(-6.500, 6.500, -6.500, 6.500, -6.00, 12.00);

}

int main( int argc, char * argv[])
{

    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH );
    glutInitWindowPosition(50, 100);
    glutInitWindowSize(1000, 1000);
    glutCreateWindow("test");
    glutReshapeFunc(herschaal);
    init();
    glutDisplayFunc(drawScene);
    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
}
```

the original export from blender: http://hastebin.com/owubizotuv.hs

the file with v-vertices I use, aka myVertices.h: http://hastebin.com/lirajuhiqe.avrasm

Comment: You have a point cloud, but trying to draw polygons. Polygons do not magically emerge from point clouds. Your Blender export file has faces in addition to vertices. You need to use them.

Comment: @n.m. how? Would you mind giving a more precise explanation. I mean, look at the cube (that I don t need). It is almost done. Shall I ue the vn and f coordinates as well to do that?

Comment: My guess is the problem is the data loader. And you do not have that code in your post. Please post that code as well.

Comment: @Andreas what do you mean by the dataloader? I posted almost all the code I wrote. The only thing I didn't post is the one that puts all the vertices from the blender file between curly brackets {} and adds the comma's

Comment: Exactly. Meshes come in quads, triangles, strips, indexed... Are you sure you intepret the mesh accordingly?

Comment: @Andreas, IDK I have a hard time understanding what you mean exactly. Do you have an example or so to illustrate what you mean? I am using glBegin(GL_POLYGON); to draw the personage if this is what you mean.

Comment: I don´t know how familiar you are with obj so I´ll try from the begining. Don´t be mad :) (Also my obj-haxing is rusty...) Your obj-file has vertex position and normals, "v" and "vn". There is an "s" before the index section saying "off". I assume that means "no strips". After that are indices to the vertices forming quads. Sound familiar so far?

Comment: @Andreas, that s pretty new for me. But I understand what u just wrote.

Comment: @Andreas How can I detect whether the vertex in my header file is part of a quad triangle, etc... (if that is what you mean and what I have to do)?

Comment: Look at this line from the blender file: `f 1008//48 1026//48 1023//48 1005//48`. How do you interpret it?

Comment: Vertex Normal Indices Without Texture Coordinate Indices. A vertex  matches the corresponding vertex elements of a previously defined vertex list. that s it idk what the numbers represent (some coordinates I guess)

Comment: Obj files tell you if it is point, line, triangle or quad by the number of coordinates for one f. In your case it is 4 hence quads. As you cant draw 3d polygon form a mesh (can draw only 2d polygon in 3d space) I find the error most probable being you don't parse the obj correctly, ie as quads.

Comment: @Andreas according to this tutorial: http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-7-model-loading/ (But I write c-code) I have parsed the export. Now I have the different vertex indexes and normal vertex indexes in a table. The question I have is what elements should I pass to the function glVertex3fv(); ? The v-coordinates?

my code: http://dpaste.com/0DS108E

Comment: Yes. However the topology is quads, not polygons. Try changing GL_POLYGON to GL_QUADS in your draw function. I say "try" because not sure if you parse to quad mesh or triangle mesh from the obj.